# Manipulating subsections of an array

Tags: image, r, thumbnails

I am using R to plot trying to conditionally change parts of an array
based on the columns of the array.

I have worked out the following steps:

```
x<-array(1,dim=c(4,4,3))
r<-x[,,1]
g<-x[,,2]
b<-x[,,3]

r1<-apply(r[,2:3],1:2,function(f){return(0)})
g1<-apply(g[,2:3],1:2,function(f){return(0)})
b1<-apply(b[,2:3],1:2,function(f){return(0)})

r3<-cbind(r[,1],r1,r[,4])
g3<-cbind(g[,1],g1,g[,4])
b3<-cbind(b[,1],b1,b[,4])

# Pass to pixmapRGB
```

This works, but as I am new to R, I was wondering if
there was a more efficient way to manipulate parts
of an array.

For example, does apply know which element it is working on?

The bigger picture is that I want to graph a time-series scatter
plot over many pages.

I would like to have a thumbnail in the corner of the page that is
a graph of the whole series.  I would like to color a portion of
that thumbnail a different color to indicate what range the
current page is examining.

There is alot of data, so it is not feasible to redraw a new plot
for the thumbnail on every page.

What I have done is to first write the thumbnail plot out to a tiff file.
Then I read the tiff file back in, used getChannels from pixmap
to break the picture into arrays, and used the above code to change
some of the pixels based on column.
Finally I then print the image to a viewport using
  pixmapRGB/pixmapGrob/grid.draw

It seems like alot of steps.  I would be grateful for any pointers
that would help me make this more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but if what you're trying to do is just "change some pixels based on column," why don't you just use the basic array indexing to do that?

This will do the same thing you have posted:

```
x<-array(1,dim=c(4,4,3))
r<-x[,,1]
g<-x[,,2]
b<-x[,,3]
r[,2:3]=0
g[,2:3]=0
b[,2:3]=0
```

Is that helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the information, I need to remember to think about array assignments...But my example was slightly too simple.

The thumbnail is greyscale, and the code really checks to see
if the pixel is white.  If so, changes it to red.

If not white, it would increase the red value to make it shaded red.

Comment: How about this: r[which(r==0)] = 3;   r[which(r!=0)] = r[which(r!=0)]+1

Comment: My original idea needed both which, and column. :) I went back and used the array indexing in your first solution, and just slightly reddened everything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more of a comment than an answer, but when I try to plot over a number of pages I usually go left to right, breaking up the plots into quantiles and setting appropriate `xlim` (or `ylim`)

```
x <- rnorm(100000)
y <- rnorm(100000)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
seq1 <- quantile(df$x, probs = seq(0,1,0.1))
seq2 <- quantile(df$x, probs = seq(0,1,0.1))

for(x in 1:(length(seq1)-1)) { 
  plot(df, xlim=c(seq1[x],seq1[x+1]))
}
```

No idea how to overlay a thumbnail onto the graphs although I think you could do this with one of the `rimage` functions if you saved the thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I have been using ggplot and grid.  I do something similar, but break it up into 6 rows of 30 minutes on each page.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid having to read and paste a tiff thumbnail by actually replotting the whole chart at reduced scale.  check out `par(fig)` , and then do  something like

`Rgames: plot(1:2,1:2)`

`Rgames: par(mar=c(.1,6,.1,.1),new=T,fig=c(0,.25,.5,.75))`

`Rgames: plot(1:2,1:2)`

`Rgames: polygon(c(1,2,2,1),c(1,1,2,2),col='red')`

("Rgames:" is my prompt)
You'll have to play a bit with the margin values, but this will get your "mini-graph" set up.

Comment: Hello Carl, 
  Unfortunately, this doesn't help.
My data set is rather large.  
( Largest one I have been working with is 10.6 Million Rows )

In a smaller set of 183k,: the large plot, and the smaller plot take 
the same amount of time.

Comment: Well, since the small plot is just for "show",  you could always plot a small subset or a rasterized image.  See `rasterImage` and related tools.